# calculated column with moving average

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to create a calculated column with moving average using the code below.

```
SELECT * FROM ibstocks.stocks;
ALTER TABLE stocks
ADD COLUMN MA100 decimal as (cast(AVG(close) OVER(partition by Symbol order by date ROWS BETWEEN 9 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) as decimal(8,2)))
```

I am receving the following error message:

> Error Code: 3593. You cannot use the window function 'avg' in this context.'.

Could you please advise?

Thank you.

Comment: You can't and shouldn't consider this unless you have static data or fear performance issues when included in a query.

Comment: In the documantation is said, you can use only deterministic functions for generated columns, and the avg window function isn't deterministic( not always the same value for this row)

Comment: You could move the logic to a view, if performance is not critical.

Answer (score 0):

If you have static data, one option is to add the declaration of the new field and separately use an `UPDATE` statement to generate your window function as you intended in first instance:

```
ALTER TABLE stocks ADD COLUMN MA100 decimal(8,2);

WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, AVG(close_) OVER(PARTITION BY Symbol ORDER BY date_ ROWS BETWEEN 9 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS running_avg
    FROM stocks
)
UPDATE     stocks
INNER JOIN cte 
        ON stocks.Symbol = cte.Symbol
       AND stocks.date_ = cte.date_
SET stocks.MA100 = cte.running_avg;
```

Check the demo [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/TjT3omkB2m7njSSRctbcW/0).

Comment: Unless the data is static I wouldn't trust this.